# Angular2: Passing an object to bind event from parent to child

Tags: angular, binding, components, bind, communication

The binding works fine for title, subtitle, button.icon and button.name but not for button.action

parent.component.html

```
    <app-title [title]="title" [subtitle]="subtitle" [buttons]="buttons"></app-title>
```

parent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {

actionOne() {
    ...
}

title = 'Title';
subtitle = 'Subtitle';
buttons = [
    { 'name': 'Name1', 'icon': 'Icon1', 'action': 'actionOne()'},
    { 'name': 'Name2', 'icon': 'Icon2', 'action': 'actionTwo()'},
    { 'name': 'Name3', 'icon': 'Icon3', 'action': 'actionThree()'}
];
```

}

child.component.html

```
<section>
<div class="text-wrapper">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <h2 *ngIf="subtitle">{{ subtitle }}</h2>
</div>
 <template *ngIf="buttons">
        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <button *ngFor="let button of buttons" md-raised-button (click)="button.action"><md-icon *ngIf="button.icon">{{ button.icon }}</md-icon>{{ button.name }}</button>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent  {

@Input() title:string;
@Input() subtitle:string;
@Input() buttons:string;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do:

Button interface:

```
export interface IButton {
  Name: string;
  Icon: string;
  Action: Function
}
```

Parent component:

```
@Component({
...
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  buttons: IButton[] = [
    {
      Name: 'Hello',
      Icon: 'Test',
      Action: this.actionOne.bind(this) // we need to make sure this is scoped correctly
    }
  ];

  actionOne(){
    console.log('This is from action One');
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Child component

```
@Component({
...
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() buttons: IButton[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Child html

```
<div *ngIf="buttons">
  <button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="button.Action()">{{button.Name}}</button>
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: how to handle a scenario that button.Action get multiple parameters like actionOne(para1, para2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work, since you are passing string literals, not method references, to the child. For instance, in the `button.action` property, your `ChildComponent` sees the string literal `"actionOne()"`, not the method `actionOne()`.

In order to pass the method references when declaring the buttons, you'd have to remove the quotes and parentheses around the method names and prefix them with `this.`:

```
buttons = [
    { 'name': 'Name1', 'icon': 'Icon1', 'action': this.actionOne },
    { 'name': 'Name2', 'icon': 'Icon2', 'action': this.actionTwo },
    { 'name': 'Name3', 'icon': 'Icon3', 'action': this.actionThree }
]
```

But still, it won't work as the context for `this` will be lost in the `ChildComponent`.

What I would do is use string literals in the buttons declarations (similar to your code, but WITHOUT the parentheses, e.g. `'actionOne'`, `'actionTwo'`...) and whenever a button is clicked in the child, I would emit an `@Output` event to the parent:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="buttonClicked.emit(button.action)">
      {{ button.name }}
    </button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Output() buttonClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Notice that I'm passing the `button.action` property (string) when emitting the event.

Now, the `ParentComponent` can listen to that event and use the received string as an identifier to decide which local method to call:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <child-comp (buttonClicked)="handleAction($event)"></child-comp>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent  {

  handleAction(actionName) {
    // Here, put some logic to call a local method based on `actionName`
    // Something like this[actionName]();
  }

  actionOne() {
      ...
  }

  actionTwo() {
      ...
  }

}
```